# MVC5: route two different urls into one action method designating them by the input parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

Let's assume I have a following action method:

```
[Route("option/{id:int}")] // routing is incomplete
public ActionResult GetOption(int id, bool advanced)
{
    ...
    return View();
}
```

This action should be associated with two different routes:

- the one that fetches results in a simple form: `.../option/{id}`,
- and its advanced version: `.../option/{id}/advanced`.

It is important to represent these routes as **two separate urls**, and not the same URL with optional query string parameter. The only difference between these URLs is in the last term, which is basically some form of designation. What I need is a way to setup the routing rules to tell framework that it should call same method for both types of requests passing true as a second parameter in case of *'advanced'* requests, or false otherwise. There are substantial reasons why I need to encapsulate both routes into one action method. So, no, I can't add second method to handle 'advanced' requests separately.

The question is: How to setup such routing?

Comment: Are you willing to change the type of the second parameter?

Comment: @Nkosi, I would prefer to see it as a boolean flag, because it makes more sense in this scenario. But if there are no ways to bind a bool... Do you want to suggest a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to change the type of the second parameter

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("option/{id:int}")] // GET option/1
[Route("option/{id:int}/{*advanced}")] // GET option/1/advanced
public ActionResult GetOption(int id, string advanced) {
    bool isAdvanced = "advanced".Equals(advanced);

    //...

    return View();
}
```

And as much as you are apposed to having separate actions you can simpy have one call the other to avoid repeating code (DRY)

```
// GET option/1
[HttpGet]
[Route("option/{id:int}")] 
public ActionResult GetOption(int id, bool advanced = false) {
    //...    
    return View("Option");
}

// GET option/1/advanced
[HttpGet]
[Route("option/{id:int}/advanced")]
public ActionResult GetAdvancedOption(int id) {
    return GetOption(id, true);
}
```

Comment: Well, second solution is obvious, but it doesn't suite requirements. It have to be single action method for both routes. As for the first solution - it's working, much appreciated, even though I would prefer not to change type of designator. Maybe you have other ideas how to implement this without modifying action signature?